# Why is there a 1px roundoff error when centering images and how to work around it?

Tags: html, css

It's best to see it yourself, so check out this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6rc4zzcv/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container
            {
                background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
                background-position: center top;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                min-width: 302px;
                background-color: yellow;
                border: 1px solid blue;
            }
            #centerbox
            {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                border: 1px solid lime;
                margin: auto;
                position: relative
            }
            #floater
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 101px;
                width: 98px;
                height: 98px;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="centerbox">
                <div id="floater"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you resize the browser window (or just the fiddle output window), sometimes the red square stays exactly within the black frame, and sometimes there's a 1px gap. I checked this in Chrome and IE11. IE11 seems to try and render "half-pixel", so it's less noticeable, but still there. Curiously, if the background image is smaller than the viewport, this does not happen.

I can imagine the cause for this effect (the centering code is duplicated in two places, for background and for margins, and uses different rounding methods) - but how to work around it?

In real life, the black box is actually an artistically drawn box which merges with the background, so I'd really rather avoid splitting it out.

Comment: Have you tried making the red box and the black border around it an odd width (rather than even)? I think this is just a drawing issue in the browser, it works ok in FF.

Comment: @thePav - Wow, interesting! That actually HELPED in Chrome. IE11 is still  the same though. I'll install Firefox too.

Comment: @thePav - Yes, firefox handles this perfectly. Still it's weird. Why do odd sizes work? I guess I could tell the artist to produce backgrounds with odd sizes, although it's a weird requirement. I'd rather find a way to fix it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rc4zzcv/4/)***

Yes exactly as you've noticed, the issue is that Chrome (and possibly other browsers too) *bugs* on centering large images, cause the centering calculation offset.

One solution would be, instead of setting that 2000×200px background to the parent hitting that issue, use another inner element set at

```
#bg{ /* I'm inside the parent */
    position:    relative;
    background:  url("2000x200image.jpg");
    width:       2000px;
    height:      200px;
    left:        50%;     /* center left edge */
    margin-left: -1000px; /* -half width */
}
```

as you can see above, **the element** is centered! and will move same as all other centered elements on the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="centerbox">
        <div id="bg"></div>
        <div id="floater"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    min-width: 302px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#bg{
    position:relative;
    width:2000px; /* same as your image size */
    height:200px;
    /* center element instead of image! */
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left:-1000px; /* -half width */
    background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...=');
}
#centerbox{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
    margin: auto;  
    position: relative;
}
#floater{
    position: absolute;
    top: 51px;
    left: 101px;
    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Not in this case - the background is pretty big, it covers the whole page. :( Umm, you can see this in real life in www.drowtales.com. OK, so it's a bug. Guess I'll report it.

Comment: @Vilx- report. But use my suggestion to get it working on every browser. There's no other way AFAIK.

Comment: Oh, wait, I just read what you did there! Seems good, I'll try that!

Comment: @Vilx- also, instead of using a specific `#bg DIV element`, you can simply use `<img id="bg" src="2000x200image.jpg">` and use the same trick with negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you already know. Pixel perfection on the web is a myth. You can Google for that and find a multitude of articles about the subject. Rounding errors are the chief culprit. Bugs may be another but, perhaps, less likely. Attempting to line things up to the pixel and then hope the browser, any browser, resizes fractional calculations in your favor is never going to happen except with just luck.